# How do I build a matrix to translate one set of points to another?

Tags: c++, mathematics, matrix

I've got 3 points in space that define a triangle. I've also got a vertex buffer made up of three vertices, that also represent a triangle that I will refer to as a "model".

How can I can I find the matrix M that will transform vertex in my buffer to those 3 points in space ?

For example, let's say my three points A, B, C are at locations:

```
A.x = 10, A.y = 16, A.z = 8
B.x = 12, B.y = 11, B.z = 1
C.x = 19, C.y = 12, C.z = 3
```

given these coordinates how can I build a matrix that will translate and rotate my model such that both triangles have the exact same world space ? That is, I want the first vertex in my triangle model to have the same coordinates as A, the second to have the same coordinates as B, and same goes for C.

nb: I'm using instanced rendering so I can't just give each vertex the same position as my 3 points. I have a set of three points defining a triangle, and only three vertices in my vertex buffer.

Answer (score 6):

Do the transformations algebraically with a matrix of unknowns, set the result equal to the desired result. This gives you a system of linear equations, solve it, now you have a plug in formula for making such a matrix.

For translating from the points A, B and C to F, G, and H you'll get: [quickmath.com](http://www.quickmath.com/webMathematica3/quickmath/equations/solve/advanced.jsp#v1=F1%3DM11*A1%2BM21*A2%2BM31*A3%0AF2%3DM12*A1%2BM22*A2%2BM32*A3%0AF3%3DM13*A1%2BM23*A2%2BM33*A3%0AG1%3DM11*B1%2BM21*B2%2BM31*B3%0AG2%3DM12*B1%2BM22*B2%2BM32*B3%0AG3%3DM13*B1%2BM23*B2%2BM33*B3%0AH1%3DM11*C1%2BM21*C2%2BM31*C3%0AH2%3DM12*C1%2BM22*C2%2BM32*C3%0AH3%3DM13*C1%2BM23*C2%2BM33*C3&v2=M11%0AM12%0AM13%0AM21%0AM22%0AM23%0AM31%0AM32%0AM33)

Result image, in case the link breaks:

[image: Way too big bunch of formula.]

Comment: Best answer ever? :)